# Появилась ошибка в коде , не могу понять причины. Все делал по учебнику

Tags: java, android, firebase

Появилась ошибка в LfirebaseListAdapter вот код

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclirView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://kyrsovaya30.firebaseio.com/Languag");
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
        }
    };

    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Вот ошибка при компиляции

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:(47, 59) error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class 
FirebaseListAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseListOptions<String>
found: MainActivity,Class<String>,int,DatabaseReference
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseListAdapter
```

[image: скриншот кода]

Comment: Прикрепите код и ошибку в виде текста.

Comment: У вас ошибка компиляции. Посмотрите какие аргументы принимает конструктор и сравните с тем, что вы передаёте. И не надо картинок - всё должно быть в вопросе текстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последний параметр конструктора не того типа что требуется. Требуется:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<yourapp>.firebaseio.com");
```

У вас же

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = ...
```

Документация:
https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html